# Workflow conditionally Send Email based on Field value

Tags: email, notifications

This is what I have so far but I'm not sure if it is correct.

Basically I want to the workflow to do this:

If current item field equals value send email but if current item field equals different value do not send email.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will all of your items have values in those fields that match one of the conditions above? If you're mostly interested in ensuring that items only matching a specific condition trigger an email action, then I would consider changing your Else statement to reflect the opposite of your initial condition:

Else if Current Item:Status not equals Pending

Still including your log actions (and if I understand your criteria correctly), that should allow the workflow to function as you're expecting.

Cheers,

-Drew